# Protected methods in subclass access which is in different package

Tags: java, inheritance

I Have following two classes:

Class A

```
package A;
public class A {
    protected String classType(){
        return "s1";
    }
}
```

Class C

```
package B;

import A.A;

public class C extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    C c=new C();
    c.classType();//no error
    A a=new C();
    a.classType();//error
    }
}
```

Why error occurs in second one,even though we are accessing protected methods which is said to have access in subclass in different package??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to `protected` methods is granted across packages within the context of a class **extending** the parent class.

In your case, you are invoking that method on an instance of the class, hence it is not visible.

It would be if you had an instance method or statement in `C` invoking `classType()`: that would virtually invoke `super#classtype()` unless you'd overridden it in `C`.

E.g.

```
public class C extends A {
    {
        // ok, instance statement
        String foo = classType();
    }
   void foo() {
        // ok, instance method
        String foo = classType();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. :)

Comment: ,here "invoking that method on an instance of the class" means that the reference is of superclass type and invoking from it.am i right??

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf it means you are invoking it on an instance of class `C` in your case, but it clearly wouldn't work either if you were invoking it in an instance of `A`.

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf no problem.